# ¿Cómo puedo realizar el promedio de cada conjunto de 12 columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Los datos en total hacen una matriz de 468x4. La idea es sacar el promedio del caudal de cada año, por lo cual se deben tomar los 12 valores (mes 1 al 12) de cada año y sacarle el promedio, así se debe obtener para el año 1981, 1982...

| Estación | Año | Mes | Caudal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 1 | 287.6 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 2 | 246.7 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 3 | 231.7 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 4 | 257 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 5 | 376.3 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 6 | 312 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 7 | 284.6 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 8 | 294.5 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 9 | 348.7 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 10 | 528.6 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 11 | 531.1 |
| 23087210 | 1981 | 12 | 448.7 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 1 | 286.9 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 2 | 380.5 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 3 | 314 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 4 | 385.3 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 5 | 520.7 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 6 | 493.9 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 7 | 366.1 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 8 | 331.8 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 9 | 410 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 10 | 475.5 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 11 | 484.8 |
| 23087210 | 1982 | 12 | 434.7 |

He intentado plantear el código pero sólo obtengo el valor de los primeros 12 elementos correspondientes al año 1981.

```py
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 mat = np.loadtxt('23087211.txt', skiprows = 1, unpack = False)
 matc1 = mat[:, 3:468]

 # Matriz para los promedios de los caudales
 prom_anual = np.zeros(468)

 for i in range(468):
     vector_anual = matc1[0:12,i]
     panual = np.average(vector_anual)
     prom_anual[i] = panual
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo una posible solución usando `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Leemos los datos y los almacenamos en un dataframe
#Aunque ponga "read_csv" lee los txts sin problema
df = pd.read_csv('datos.txt', sep=",")

#Obtenemos la cantidad de filas que tiene el archivo,
#aunque sea una matriz 468x4, es mejor evitar el uso de números mágicos
#y que se puedan añadir datos sin modificar el código.
tam_datos = df.shape[0]

#Array (No matriz) del conjunto de los promedios
#Podrías hacer un diccionario Año:Promedio
prom_anual = []
suma_promedio = ""
#Vas sumando los valores y, cuando tengas 12 (un año) le calculas el promedio y lo almacenas en el array
for i in range(0, tam_datos):
    suma_promedio = df["Caudal"][i]
    if(i%12 == 0):
        prom_anual.append(suma_promedio/12)
        suma_promedio = 0;

#El resultado del vector sería el siguiente:
prom_anual
>> [23.96666666666667, 23.90833333333333]
```